# Regex to read code comment

Tags: javascript, regex

i have code comment block like this..

```
/**
 * This method provide inheritance to the object supplied; this method inherit the 
 * public methods from the Parent class to the Child class. this also provide
 * multiple inheritance, in which the method ambiguity is solved by the overriding
 * the last inherited class's method.
 * @access public
 * @method inherit
 * @param Object Parent
 * @param Object Child
 * @return Object
 */
```

and ignore comments like

```
/* This is a test comment for testing regex. */
```

i tried a lot to get this comment using regex in javascript and failed every time. can anyone suggest a regex for this or any other solution to extract the comment block.

Comment: Show us what you tried?

Comment: You should precise what exactly you want. And probably why the many articles on regexes for C++ style comments didn't answer your question.

Comment: i tired this /\*([^*]|[\r\n]|(\*+([^*/]|[\r\n])))*\*

Comment: Have you tried a simpler one?

Comment: Ok so you want to match ONLY multiline comments? And you want to only capture its contents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're looking for multiline comments only, here is one which does exactly that.

```
\/[*]+[\n\r][\s\S]+?[\n\r] *[*]+\/
```

Answer (score 1):

Regexp that matches comments block like your first example is `/\/\*\*[\s\S]*?\*\//`. After extracting whole comment you can do some additional parsing.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you're looking for.

- First it looks for `/**`.
- Then it matches any content within the comment as long as we find no `*/`
- Finally, it looks for a `*/` to end

Tested here at [regexpal](http://regexpal.com).

```
/\*{2}([^\*]|\*(?!/))*\*/
```